# Issue about extension install via composer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am facing issue about extension install via composer please give solution

```
 root@aadmin-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~# apt-get install composer Reading
 package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
 Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package composer
 root@aadmin-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~#
```

Comment: Is  composer install in your system??

Comment: Which magento version are you using Or which extension have you try to install using composer?

Comment: I am using magento 2.3  and https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider extention download